# is the language (a+)* the same as a*?

Tags: algorithm, regular-language

Quick question, if a is a regular expression then is it true that a* = (a+)* ?

Is (a+)* a valid expression? If it is, then can anyone explain why is it the same as a*? I apologize for asking here, but I couldn't find anything via Google.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that `L(a*) = L((a+)*)`. We can prove this by showing `L(a*)` is a subset of `L((a+)*)` and vice versa.

To show that `L(a*)` is a subset of `L((a+)*)` we must show that anything generated by `a*` is also generated by `(a+)*`. We need provide only one method of generation. The regular expression `a*` generates strings e = a^0, a = a^1, aa = a^2, ..., a^k, ..., for all integers n. To generate any of these, it suffices to choose the generated substring `a` from the subexpression `a+` and replace, which yields the same expression `a*` and obviously generates the same strings of a's in the same way.

To show that `L((a+)*)` is a subset of `L(a*)`, we need only point out that the only alphabet symbol in the expression `(a+)*` is `a`, and so that expression cannot generate anything but strings of a's. Because `a*` generates all such strings, it is similarly clear that `L((a+)*)` is a subset or `L(a*)`.

Because `L(a*)` and `L((a+)*)` are subsets of each other, the sets must be equal. That is, te expressions generate the same language and are therefore equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `(a+)*` is valid and equivalent to `a*`. The first expression means "a sequence of at least one `a`, repeated 0 or more times", and the second means "one `a`, repeated 0 or more times". Clearly both are equivalent.

Comment: So there is no difference since a+ = a* - e where e is the empty string?

Answer (score -1):

No, `(a+)*` matches the same string as `a*`, but it is an anti-pattern because of [ReDoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS). On its own the `(a+)*` is not harmful, but many regex engines can be frozen with the `"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab"` string if you use the `(a+)*x` pattern. Another difference that you have a capturing group in `(a+)*`.